# Connect to Flask localhost server through proxy IP

Tags: python, flask, proxy

I am new to Flask and web development and stuck trying to access the localhost development server through my browser, which is running through a proxy IP.

The proxy IP I have set manually from the Google Chrome advanced settings (see https://customers.trustedproxies.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=10). "Bypass proxy for local addresses" is unchecked, as I do not want to do this here - the Flask server needs to use the proxy. For general browsing, setting the proxy is fine. Also, I am using socketio to run the app.

With the proxy set in this way, I have tried these options without success:

```
socketio.run(app) # url http://127.0.0.1:5000/ or localhost:5000

socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080) # url http://127.0.0.1:8080/ or localhost:8080

socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0') # url http://0.0.0.0:5000/ or localhost:5000

socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080) # url http://0.0.0.0:8080/ or localhost:8080

socketio.run(app, host=proxyip) # url http://proxyip:5000/ or localhost:5000
```

I either get an "invalid address" error in the Python console, or a 502 error in my browser. Are there any other ways I can run the development server that may work here?

Comment: Hmm wait, you need to clarify. So flask is running on a remote server, correct? And you want to access it from your local machine? Is the proxy server, the same as the one running the flask app?

Comment: Are the comments the urls that you've tried?

Comment: @spadarian The comments are indeed the urls I am trying.

Comment: @Maresh I am running all this on my desktop, so the proxy server is not running the app, just my browser connection, and there's no remote server (if I understand this correctly). I am also using the proxy IPs with the requests module.

Comment: Why does the Flask app need to use the proxy?
The problem is that  "Bypass proxy for local addresses" is unchecked. You are asking the proxy server to resolve "localhost" (or 0.0.0.0, or 127.0.0.1) but there is nothing running on those ports in that server.

Comment: @spadarian It's a web scraper that needs proxy IP rotation to work. I think I understand, my desired approach would require running the server on the proxies IP, which is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure flask to run on `127.0.0.1` and in your proxy settings you need to enable: "bypass proxy for local address" otherwise you are trying to access localhost on the proxy and not on your local machine.

If you want to access your flask instance via a proxy that is outside of you local network you need to:
 - Run flask on 0.0.0.0:8888 (or another port)
 - From your home router, forward port 8888 to the machine running flask
 - From your browser use your external IP address (google "what is my ip") + the 8888 port to access your flask app

IMPORTANT NOTE: Doing it like described in the second solution is opening your application to the world, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I had already. I think what I was hoping to do  is not possible, so the correct answer is to do it your way i.e. default settings.

Comment: I think i finally understand what you wanted. I'll edit.